# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on my project in Django, I need the foreign key (designation) to be displayed respective to the current user. It displays perfectly fine just like I wanted, but it throws an error while I submit the form, 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'.

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\KARTHICK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\KARTHICK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\KARTHICK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\KARTHICK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "F:\TECH\emp\crm\employee\views.py", line 26, in employee_form
form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
File "F:\TECH\emp\crm\employee\forms.py", line 40, in __init__
self.fields['designation'].queryset = req.user.designation.all()
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
[16/Mar/2020 13:06:45] "POST /employee/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78894
```

**models.py**

```
class Designation(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="designation",null=True,blank=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Employee(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="employee",null=True,blank=True)                                                           
     designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
def __init__(self,req,*args,**kwargs):
    super(EmployeeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['designation'].queryset = req.user.designation.all()
```

**views.py**

```
 def employee_form(request,id=0):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    if id == 0:       
        req = request.user.designation.all()     
        form = EmployeeForm(req)
    else:

        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        if employee in request.user.employee.all():
            form = EmployeeForm(request,instance=employee)
        else:
            return redirect('/employee')
    return render(request,'employee-form.html',{'form':form})
else:
    if id==0:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
    else:

        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        if employee in request.user.employee.all():
            form = EmployeeForm(request.POST,instance=employee)
    if form.is_valid():
        n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
        t = Employee(name=n)
        t.save()
        request.user.employee.add(t)

    return redirect('/employee')
```

Comment: Show us the full error tracback and more code so we can trace the names involved (`req`, `request`, `DesignationForm`…).

Comment: added more code, I hope that it will help trace the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses. I've managed to eliminate the error. I didn't pass the request argument in the POST method

**views.py**

```
form = EmployeeForm(request,request.POST)
```

Comment: It threw another error ---
NOT NULL constraint failed: emp_employee.designation_id

Answer (score 0):

in views.py

```
def employee_form(request,id=0):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    if id == 0:       
        req = request.user.designation.all() //but here you are passing queryset    
        form = EmployeeForm(req)
```

So instead of `form = EmployeeForm(req)` use `form = EmployeeForm(request)` or `form = EmployeeForm(request.user)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)  , But  I've tried that too, still the error is same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've passed the argument 'request', and changed the forms.py as follows, self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(user=req.user)     Still got the same error . But the foreign key is perfectly filtered based on the user, while submitting the form, it throws the same error

Comment: what you want to perform in form because problem is in form's init method  `self.fields['designation'].queryset = req.user.designation.all()`

Comment: I've rectified the error bro!... But it threw another error 

NOT NULL constraint failed: emp_employee.designation_id

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
form = EmployeeForm(req)
```

to

```
form = EmployeeForm(request)
```

Your `Employee` form expects a request object as argument, but you pass it a queryset of `Designations`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've passed the argument 'request', and changed the forms.py as follows,

      self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(user=req.user)

Still got the same error